# HDFS configuration error when reading ORC data in HDFS from Vertica

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, vertica, orc

I am using Vertica 7.2 and am trying to access ORC data in HDFS. The directory location in HDFS is `'/user/<path_to_ORC_dir>/'` with all the ORC files that underlie a Hive table that is stored in ORC format.

The hadoopConfDir parameter in Vertica has been set to `/etc/hadoop/conf`. The hadoop conf directory from the separate hadoop cluster has been copied to each node in the Vertica cluster under `/etc/hadoop/conf/`. I have made an external Vertica table to read from the hdfs location using:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test (col1 INT, etc...) AS COPY FROM 'hdfs:///user/<path_to_ORC_dir>/*' on any node orc;
```

However, when I try to query from the table I get the following error

```
select * from test;

Error opening file [hdfs:///user/<path_to_ORC_dir>/000004_0] for read: Could not find HDFS configurations for [hdfs:///user/<path_to_ORC_dir>/000004_0]
```

My ORC files are named 0..._0 and the file specified in the error changes each time I query.

When I make a table using the specified file in error, instead of the entire directory, I can query the table without any problems.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test1 (col1 INT, etc...) AS COPY FROM 'hdfs:///user/<path_to_ORC_dir>/000004_0' on any node orc;

select * from test1;
...correct results...
```

What is the cause of the HDFS configuration error when trying to read the entire directory as opposed to the single file? Also to note, I can query the Hive table that is build on 'hdfs:///user//' without any problems.

Comment: Does verify_hadoop_conf_dir() yield anything interesting?

Comment: Forgot to specify, but the version of vertica I'm using 7.2, says it doesn't support that function.

Comment: Oh, oops.  Yeah, that was added in, I think, 8.0, to help with diagnosing problems like this.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that function in the Vertica 8.0 documentation. Is there anything else in 7.2 to help diagnose this problem? It is really strange that the table built on the single ORC file has no problem.

Comment: That is quite bizarre.  I don't have any more ideas right now, but I might be able to check some things tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is there literally a "..." in your path or is that just shortening for this question?

Comment: That is just shortening for this question. "hdfs:///user/...path/" is the full path to the hdfs location where the data is stored.